# Looping through pandas and writing each group of rows indexed by a value?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a data frame of the following form:

```
     id   |     x1     |   x2
---------------------------------
0     1   |    Apples  |    5 
1     1   |    Oranges |    3 
2     1   |    Apples  |    6 
3     2   |    Bananas |   4.5 
4     2   |    Oranges |    7 
5     3   |    Oranges |   5.5 
6     3   |    Apples  |    5
```

I want to loop through the data frame and write a new json file for each group of rows indexed by 'id' `record_<id>.json` :

e.g.  *record_1.json*:

```
{ "record" : [
       { "x1": "Apples" , 
         "x2":    5  
        },
       { "x1": "Oranges" , 
         "x2":    3  
        },
       { "x1": "Apples" , 
         "x2":    6  
        } 
   ]
}
```

*record_2.json*

```
{ "record" : [
       { "x1": "Bananas" , 
         "x2":   4.5  
        },
       { "x1": "Oranges" , 
         "x2":    7  
        } 
   ]
}
```

*etc...*

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, just loop through the `groupby` object:

```
for _, i in df.groupby("id"):
    print ({"record":i.drop("id",1).to_dict("records")})

{'record': [{'x1': 'Apples', 'x2': 5.0}, {'x1': 'Oranges', 'x2': 3.0}, {'x1': 'Apples', 'x2': 6.0}]}
{'record': [{'x1': 'Bananas', 'x2': 4.5}, {'x1': 'Oranges', 'x2': 7.0}]}
{'record': [{'x1': 'Oranges', 'x2': 5.5}, {'x1': 'Apples', 'x2': 5.0}]}
```